How do I check if a tx "ACTUALLY" went throught successfully
I am using Python to update a bid on Tensor. And frequently I will get a 200 back from JITO when making these transactions but they dont actually make the change. How could I confirm that these transactions actually went through or not?

As you've noticed, just sending a transaction does not guarantee that it will be executed and included in a block on-chain.
You can call confirm_transaction with the transaction signature and a confirmation level (confirmed is usually best) to make sure it was included in a block: https://github.com/michaelhly/solana-py/blob/7f2f3cb8e4028cddc5d550e39f66e031942a9884/src/solana/rpc/api.py#L1116

Thank you that is super helpful. And in the response Confirmation Response: GetSignatureStatusesResp { context: RpcResponseContext { slot: 279341447, api_version: Some("1.18.15") }, value: [Some(TransactionStatus(TransactionStatus { slot: 279341444, confirmations: Some(0), status: Ok(()), err: None, confirmation_status: Some(Confirmed) }))] } am I good to assume the TX was successful if the status = OK(())?

Yep, that should do it!
